# serialize object for kafka in flink

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to use flink for read data from kafka do some function and return the result to different Kafka topic but getting the following error. 
`org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the MapFunction is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.

`
 I'm getting messages from kafka  - making some manipulation on it and returns a list of object which i want to send to different topic.

```
class Wrapper implements Serializable{
        @JsonProperty("viewBuilderRequests")
        private ArrayList<ViewBuilderRequest> viewBuilderRequests;

        public Wrapper(){}

        public Wrapper(ArrayList<ViewBuilderRequest> viewBuilderRequests) {
            this.viewBuilderRequests = viewBuilderRequests;
        }

        public List<ViewBuilderRequest> getViewBuilderRequests() {
            return viewBuilderRequests;
        }

        public void setViewBuilderRequests(ArrayList<ViewBuilderRequest> viewBuilderRequests) {
            this.viewBuilderRequests = viewBuilderRequests;
        }
    }



public class ViewBuilderRequest implements Serializable {
    private CdmId cdmId
    private ViewBuilderOperation operation
    private List<ViewUserSystemIdentifier> viewUserSystemIdentifiers
    public ViewBuilderRequest(){
}

    public CdmId getCdmId() {
        return cdmId;
    }

    public void setCdmId(CdmId cdmId) {
        this.cdmId = cdmId;
    }

    public ViewBuilderOperation getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setOperation(ViewBuilderOperation operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public List<ViewUserSystemIdentifier> getViewUserSystemIdentifiers() {
        return viewUserSystemIdentifiers;
    }

    public void setViewUserSystemIdentifiers(List<ViewUserSystemIdentifier> viewUserSystemIdentifiers) {
        this.viewUserSystemIdentifiers = viewUserSystemIdentifiers;
    }

    public enum ViewBuilderOperation implements Serializable{
        Create, Update,Delete
    }




private MapFunction<String, Wrapper> parseAndSendToGraphProcessing = s ->{
    UserMatchingRequest userMatchingRequest = objectMapper.readValue(s, UserMatchingRequest.class);
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(janusGraphDataProcessing.handleMessage(userMatchingRequest));
    return wrapper;
};
```

inner classes implements Serializable too

exception is thrown from this code:

`dataStream.map(parseAndSendToGraphProcessing)
        .addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<Wrapper>(kafkaConfiguration.getBootstrapServers(),"graphNotifications",new WrapperSchema()));`

I also have de/serialization to both objects.

```
public class WrapperSchema implements DeserializationSchema<Wrapper>, SerializationSchema<Wrapper> {
//        private final static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

    static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
        public Wrapper deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(message, Wrapper.class);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEndOfStream(Wrapper nextElement) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(Wrapper element) {
//            return element.toString().getBytes();
            if(objectMapper == null) {
                objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
                objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            }
            try {
                String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(element);
                return json.getBytes();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return new byte[0];
        }

        @Override
        public TypeInformation<Wrapper> getProducedType() {
            return TypeInformation.of(Wrapper.class);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For flink to work both your messages and your map functions must be serializable.

It looks like your messages are serializable, as far as I can tell.

But your map function isn't. It's sometime difficult to get lambda to be serializable. I think in your case the problem is that the `parseAndSendToGraphProcessing` is using `objectMapper` and `janusGraphDataProcessing`, which must be serializable.

My guess is that `janusGraphDataProcessing` isn't serializable (OjbectMapper is if your using jackson 2.1 or later).

If it's the case then one work around is to write a custom RichMapFunction class that would store the `janusGraphDataProcessing` as a transient variable and initialize it in it's `open` function.

```
private MapFunction<String, Wrapper> parseAndSendToGraphProcessing = s ->{
    UserMatchingRequest userMatchingRequest = objectMapper.readValue(s, UserMatchingRequest.class);
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(janusGraphDataProcessing.handleMessage(userMatchingRequest));
    return wrapper;
};
```